# Tensorflow with softmax, to implement word2vec: Value Error: No gradients provided for andy variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, word2vec, word-embedding

I try to implement the Word2Vec Algorithm for learning in Tensorflow, but got stuck and have no idea how to solve that.

The error I get is:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ...

I have created a simpler example of my code to show the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Data
x_data = np.array([[1., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]])
y_data = np.array([[0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 1.], [1., 0., 0.]])

# Configuration
vocabulary_size = 3
embedding_size = 3
learning_rate = 0.001
training_steps = 1000

# Create network layers
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, vocabulary_size))

hidden_layer = tf.nn.relu(
    tf.add(
        tf.matmul(X, tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size]))),
        tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([embedding_size], 1))
    )
)
output_layer = tf.matmul(hidden_layer, tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([embedding_size, vocabulary_size])))

# create loss computation and optimizer
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, vocabulary_size))

cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels=Y,
    logits=X
)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)

# Initialize stuff and make calculations
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    feed_dict = {X: x_data, Y: y_data}
    for i in range(training_steps):
        _, pred_vals, loss_val = sess.run([optimizer, output_layer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

My research makes me think that the placeholders in the softmax are the problem here, but I don't really understand why and I'm not really sure about this. What is it really I'm doing wrong? And how can I solve that? :-) Solutions, Ideas?

Comment: Are you aware that you're essentially skipping the whole network when you do your `cross_entropy` passing `X` as `logits`? I think what you were aiming for looks more like `cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y, logits=output_layer)`

Comment: It seems like I was'nt that I was aware of it. Thank you. Right now I feel a little bit stupid.

Comment: We've all been there ;) I'm glad it was of help! :)